# How to get Product Element from Cart.Item

Tags: shopify, liquid

```
{% if shop.locale == 'vi' %}
  <div class="totals">
    <h2 class="totals__subtotal">Giá tiền tại Việt Nam:</h2>
    <p class="totals__subtotal-value" id="vietnam-total-price"></p>
  </div>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var vietnamTotalPriceElement = document.getElementById('vietnam-total-price');
      var cartItems = {{ cart.items | json }};

      var totalVietnamPrice = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < cartItems.length; i++) {
        var item = cartItems[i];
        var productPrice = parseFloat(item.product.metafields.custom.vietnam_price) || 0;
        var productQuantity = item.quantity;
        var linePrice = productPrice * productQuantity;
        totalVietnamPrice += linePrice;
      }

      var localizedTotalPrice = new Intl.NumberFormat('vi-VN', { style: 'currency', currency: 'VND' }).format(totalVietnamPrice);
      vietnamTotalPriceElement.innerHTML = localizedTotalPrice;
    });
  </script>
{% endif %}
```

i'm trying to get a metafields from Product class but cart.item doesn't have it, please help me!
i know the old Shopify API still works but somehow the 2.0 remove it?

Comment: Are you sure the name of the metafield is correct?
`cart.items` returns a `line_item` which holds a product. This product should have all the metafields defined for the product.
In the Shopify API Docs (https://shopify.dev/docs/api/liquid/objects/product) it is also noted that the product has the metafields.
Are you on the correct product which has a metafield with this name?